# How do you delete all manytomany relationships in a model in form_valid?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am making a booking system with Django. I want to be able to have a view to "cancel" bookings. This involves setting the participants (manytomany) of the model to None and the booked_by to none. I don't want to delete the booking as someone else might like to book it later instead. I suppose the ability to delete all relationships in manytomany for the BookingSlot would work. I would like to be able to do this in form_valid().

```
#views.py
class CancelBookingView(UpdateView):
    form_class = CancelBookingForm
    model = BookingSlot

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.booked_by = None #This works fine 
        form.instance.participants.all = None #This doesn't work
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

So far as you can see what I have tried, it hasn't worked. Help would be much appreciated, thank you!

```
#models.py
class BookingSlot(models.Model):
    start_time = models.TimeField("Start Time")
    end_time = models.TimeField("End Time")
    date = models.DateField("Date")
    location = models.ForeignKey(Court, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    booked_by = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=None, blank=True, null=True, related_name="bookedBy_CustomerUser")
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, default=None, blank=True, related_name="participant_CustomerUser")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all objects from the related object, use [**`clear()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.clear) ([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.clear)) method:

```
form.instance.participants.clear()
```

> Note that `add()`, `create()`, `remove()`, `clear()`, and `set()` all
> apply database changes immediately for all types of related fields. In
> other words, there is no need to call save() on either end of the
> relationship.